# STM32 перенос вектора прерываний

Tags: arm, stm32, ini

Доброго времени суток.
Согласно теории, контроллер на основе ARM CORTEXM3 архитектуры начинает работаь с того что загружает с нулевого адреса указатель на стек, а адреса 4 указатель на Reset прерывание.
Вопроса два:
-**ПЕРВЫЙ**  нулевой адрес имеется с учетом офсета на начало флеша (в СТМ флеш начинается с адреса 0х8000000)  ? Тоесть когда говорится  "0x0" имеется в виду  "0x8000000" ? (согласно ликовщику так должно быть)
-**ВТОРОЙ** зачем в стандартной функции  инициилизации SystemInit() выполняется перенос вектора прерываний НА ТОТ ЖЕ АДРЕС ЧТО И В ЛИНКЕРЕ ?? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При старте контроллер действительно читает с нулевого адреса таблицу прерываний, в том числе указатель стека. Регистр `SCB->VTOR` равен нулю. А по нулевому адресу в STM32 располагается загрузочное ПЗУ. Все функции загрузочного ПЗУ известны только производителю, но именно эта программа как раз устанавливает `SCB->VTOR` равным `0x08000000`. В скрипте линковщика отдельно прописывается константа адреса флеш-памяти, и дальнейшее размещение блоков (таблицы прерываний, секции кода, секции данных) происходит относительно этой константы.

Допустим, контроллер уже запустил программу начиная с адреса ResetHandler, который хранится в таблице прерываний. После этого вы можете совершенно спокойно записывать любое значение в регистр `SCB->VTOR`, и контроллер подхватит новую таблицу прерываний. Разумеется, предварительно нужно удостовериться, что в новом местоположении находится корректная таблица прерываний. Это может пригодиться, если вам требуется на лету менять обработчики прерываний.

Comment: А вот в ответе на сайте арм был другой ответ для stm32. Там сказали, что flash-память stm32 отображается на адрес 0 (mapping). И всё стартует естественным образом без участия вашего загрузочного ПЗУ.