# Векторы прерываний/исключения в STM32, Ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, stm32, arm

Изучаю файл Startup для STM32, и не могу понять один момент. Сказано, что векторы прерываний и исключений находятся в начале ПЗУ. Есть директива AREA, а у неё два параметра  CODE и DATA. В книге написано, что параметр DATA соответствует памяти ОЗУ, а CODE памяти программ - FLASH. Вопрос, почему объявление векторов производится в памяти данных т.е. ОЗУ? Прикрепляю листинг. Конкретно не понятна секция - AREA RESET, DATA,READONLY. Ведь должно быть CODE, а не DATA. Заранее спасибо.

```
; Программый модуль стартового файла StartUp_1
; Определить переменную "Размер стека" (1 К байт)
Stack_Size      EQU     0x00000400
; Объявить секцию данных для размещения стека системы
; без инициализации памяти, с атрибутом выравнивания 
; по 8 байтам
                                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
; Зарезервировать область памяти под стек 
; с числом байт Stack_Size            
Stack_Mem       SPACE   Stack_Size      ; (1 К байт)
; Метка вершины стека (авто-декрементный стек)
__initial_sp

; Vector Table 
; Объявить секцию для размещения таблицы векторов 
; прерываний/исключений
; Для компановщика определяется как область памяти 
; данных RESET. Будет автоматически размещена компоновщиком 
; в начале памяти программ
                AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
; Объявить параметры таблицы векторов - глобальными именами
                EXPORT  __Vectors
                EXPORT  __Vectors_End
                EXPORT  __Vectors_Size
; Инициализация векторов обработчиков 
; прерываний/исключений
__Vectors       DCD     __initial_sp    ; Вершина стека - Top of Stack 
                                DCD     Reset_Handler ; Точка выхода в обработчик исключения
                                                                            ; по сбросу процессора Reset Handler
                                DCD     NMI_Handler   ; Точка входа в обработчик
                                                                            ; немаскируемого прерывания NMI
;                               ...
; Далее по аналогии могут быть объявлены и остальные 
; вектора обработчиков прерываний/исключений
__Vectors_End
__Vectors_Size  EQU     __Vectors_End - __Vectors

; Объявление кодовой секции для размещения 
; подпрограмм обработчиков прерываний/исключений
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В STM32 имеется возможность разместить вектора не только во флеш, но и в ОЗУ и при этом так же можно указать для них адрес. Советую прочитать ответ на [STM32 перенос вектора прерываний](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752988/stm32-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
Ну и затем все настроить в соответствии с требованиями проекта. Например в bootloader было бы логично разместить вектора в ОЗУ или так же во флеше по адресу начала программы. Самое главное, указать контроллеру на адрес векторов в регистре *SCB->VTOR* соответствующий адресу в который компилятор разместил вектора.

Откуда, кстати, такой странный файл Startup? Среди файлов с библиотекой периферии STM32 нет подходящего?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нашел книгу по ядру Cortex-M3, изучаю её активно,  и вот там такой файл инициализации сокращенный в целях обучения.
Тогда еще вопросик-получается директивой DCD мы выделяем память в ОЗУ  для векторов. А потом как бы соединяем обработчик во флеше с адресом этого вектора?

Comment: Если вектора размещаются во флеше, то они сразу же распологаются в нужном месте, как правило в самом начале программы. Если же вектора требуется разместить в ОЗУ, то в любом случае они должны быть сохранены во флеш памяти (при выключении питания ОЗУ ведь очищается) и уже от туда при запуске программы, сама программа их копирует в область ОЗУ после чего записывает в регистр контроллера адрес нового размещения векторов.

Comment: Никак не могу понять, зачем векторы располагать в ОЗУ, если они всё равно будут располагаться во ПЗУ.

Comment: Причины могут разные быть, например бутлоадер, который имеет возможность перезаписать сам себя. Он загружается, копирует себя в ОЗУ, переносит вектора и запускает выполнение из ОЗУ, таким образом он сможет очистить всю флешу и записать новыми данными. Или, например, запуск программы с флеш карты, без перезаписи флеши контроллера.

Comment: теперь понятно, большое спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: Если вопросов больше нет и ответ помог, тогда надо бы принять ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Сорри, не знал, я пока новенький)

Answer (score 1):

А с чего вы взяли, что таблица векторов находится в озу? Ведь определяющим фактором является атрибут READONLY(только чтение), значит это область FLASH. А атрибут READWRITE (чтение/запись) соответствует SRAM. И файл вовсе не странный такое же начало и в оригинале от ST. Только в оригинале отсутствуют русскоязычные комментарии и присутствует объявление кучи
HEAP(по видимому ее опустили для упрощения, я так понимаю файл учебно-боевой :)). А векторы прерываний и исключений действительно находятся по адресу 0x08000000 - вершина стека, 0х08000001 - точка входа(reset_handler), а далее пошли остальные прерывания.(0x08000000 начальный адрес FLASH)

---

Теория:
Разбить программу на отдельные секции позволяет специальная директива — AREA. Она имеет следующий синтаксис: AREA Section_Name {,type} {, attr} …, где:

Section_name — имя секции.
type — тип секции. Для секции, содержащей данные нужно указывать тип DATA, а для секции, содержащей команды — тип CODE.
attr — дополнительные атрибуты. Например, атрибуты readonly или readwrite указывают в какой памяти должна размещаться секция, атрибут align=0..31 указывает каким образом секция должна быть выровнена в памяти, атрибут noinit используется для выделения областей памяти, которые не нужно инициализировать или инициализирующиеся нулями (при использовании этого атрибута можно не указывать тип секции, поскольку он может использоваться только для секций данных).
А лучше черпать из: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/default.htm

---

Как выше было сказано таблицу векторов действительно можно переносить по другому адресу(FLASH и даже SRAM), но это совсем другая тема.

PS: вот начало файла от ST startup_stm32f10x_hd.s(здесь только код без начальных комментариев):

```
Stack_Size      EQU     0x00000400

                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
Stack_Mem       SPACE   Stack_Size
__initial_sp



Heap_Size       EQU     0x00000200

                AREA    HEAP, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
__heap_base
Heap_Mem        SPACE   Heap_Size
__heap_limit

                PRESERVE8
                THUMB                       



                AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
                EXPORT  __Vectors
                EXPORT  __Vectors_End
                EXPORT  __Vectors_Size

__Vectors       DCD     __initial_sp               ; Top of Stack
                DCD     Reset_Handler              ; Reset Handler
                DCD     NMI_Handler                ; NMI Handler
                DCD     HardFault_Handler          ; Hard Fault Handler
                DCD     MemManage_Handler          ; MPU Fault Handler
                DCD     BusFault_Handler           ; Bus Fault Handler
                DCD     UsageFault_Handler         ; Usage Fault Handler
```